Mismatched allocation/deallocation error using Intel Inspector
Consider the following minimal working example:
program p
    type t
        integer,allocatable::i
    end type
    type(t),allocatable::o
    allocate(o)
    deallocate(o)
end

This code was compiled with the Intel compiler (ifx 2024.2.1) and flags -O2 -g. Analyzing the executable with the Intel Inspector (inspxe-cl 2022.1) and option --collect mi3 leads to an error:
P1: Error: Mismatched allocation/deallocation: New
 P1.2: Error: Mismatched allocation/deallocation: New
  a.out!0x8ac1: Error X2: Mismatched deallocation site: Function do_deallocate_all: Module ./a.out
  ./a.f90(6): Error X3: Allocation site: Function MAIN_: Module ./a.out

Changing the optimization flag for compilation to -O0 won't remove the deallocate statement, and the error line starting with a.out!0x8ac1 will point to the line in the code with this statement instead:
  ./a.f90(7): Error X2: Mismatched deallocation site: Function MAIN_: Module ./a.out

Why does Intel Inspector consider this an error and how to fix it?

I forgot to mention: this happens because the type contains an allocatable variable i.

You mean how to fix the Inspector to not produce false positive reports? That is up to Intel developers to do so. Report the problem through usual official channels.

@VladimirFГероямслава I was not sure, if it was a false positive report (I will contact the Intel developers). I know how to cause this error in C, but is it possible at all to produce the true error in Fortran?

I just noticed that the Intel Inspector is deprecated, so this bug won't ever be fixed.

As already discussed in the comments to the question, this is a false positive of the Intel Inspector. As of 28.03.2024, this software is deprecated, so this issue will not be fixed. Intel recommends using the Sanitizers in the new versions of their compilers (e.g. -fsanitize=address compilation flag) or Valgrind instead.
(I think it makes sense to keep this question in case someone stumbles across the same problem.)

That's really bad news. It's not as if there is a glut of dynamic analysis tools or that any of them can claim to be the one that is one size that fits all.

@PaulFloyd yes. Also, in contrast to Inspector, the new alternative for finding uninitialized memory access with the new Sanitizers (-fsanitize=memory) will not work properly, if the program uses MKL or MPI (source). (Although, I didn't check Inspector on false positives.)
